# CSS selectors: element that is child of element with id

Tags: css

Is there are CSS selector for elements under an id? Like there is for class.

It's not possible for me to change the class of the inner ul, but I need only the ul inside "the_id" to be affected. I could use javascript, but am hoping for a css solution.

```
<div id = "the_id">
    <ul>affected<ul>
</div>
<ul>not affected<ul>
```

css:

```
#the_id ul{list-style:none}
```

Comment: your css code is correct, but you should also insert a list-item `<li>...</li>` inside your list

Comment: your CSS should work if you insert <li>...</li> item. If still not working then you have to understand CSS point concept clearly. If not working try **#the_id ul{list-style:none !important}** .Cheers

Comment: seriously, googling css child selector would be a matter of seconds...

Comment: @Christoph I don't believe the author is aware of terms like "child", "sibling" or what so ever. One problem about searching for an information if you can't use the right terms for your problem.

Comment: @kleinfreund take a look at his question title - all relevant keywords are included there.

Comment: I actually looked here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp and didn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
/* any descendant */
#the_id ul
   {list-style:none}

/* OR */

/* only children */
#the_id > ul
   {list-style:none;}


<div id="the_id">
    <ul><li>affected</li><ul>
</div>
<ul><li>not affected</li><ul>
```

also, use `id="the_id"` instead of `id = "the_id"`